# Issue to recreate a group by using SCIM in WSO2 IS 5.0?

Tags: wso2-identity-server

I am using IS 5.0 and I created a group in wso2 IS using SCIM named 'developer' and also deleted the same group  using SCIM. Both operations had worked fine.Now i need to create  a group  with same name 'developer' but i am getting following error

```
{"Errors":[{"description":"Error when adding SCIM Attributes for the group:     PRIMARY/developer A Group with the sameme already exists.","code":"500"}]}
```

Any suggestion ? thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known issue (here is the [JiRA](https://wso2.org/jira/browse/IDENTITY-2827)) which will be fixed in upcoming release. If you need a patch for this, please come through WSO2 [support](http://wso2.com/support/).

Thanks!

Comment: is related to - https://wso2.org/jira/browse/IDENTITY-3095?jql=text%20~%20%22scim%20delete%20group%22