# Issue to delete a group by using SCIM in WSO2 IS 5.0

Tags: scim, wso2-identity-server

I am using IS 5.0 and I deleted a group named 'developer' in wso2 IS using SCIM service but entry not deleted from table IDN_SCIM_GROUP. when get the details of same user i got error

```
{"Errors":[{"description":"Groups not found in the user store for the filter: displayNameEqdeveloper","code":"404"}]}
```

so i created group again with same name 'developer'  but i am getting following error

```
{"Errors":[{"description":"Error when adding SCIM Attributes for the group:     PRIMARY/developer A Group with the same already exists.","code":"500"}]}
```

Thanks for any suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After adding the `SCIMEnabled` property in the usersore(demo.xml), this error didn't come.
The SCIMUserOperationListener is responsible for managing the group attributes. This listener gets triggered only if SCIMEnabled property is set to true in the user store configuration. You could enable this from the UserStoreManagement UI for secondary user stores and directly edit the `user-mgt.xml` for primary user stores. (here is the [JiRA](https://wso2.org/jira/browse/IDENTITY-3095?jql=text%20~%20%22scim%20delete%20group%22))

Comment: Related to Related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31450499/issue-to-recreate-a-group-by-using-scim-in-wso2-is-5-0 SO post.